# Difference of two increasing functions.

Tags: functions

Let $f$, and $g$, both be an increasing function w.r.t $x$, s.t $x\in(0,1)$. What can we comment on the nature of $f-g$?

Comment: Why not try a few examples?

Comment: Perhaps that it can't have too many jump discontinuities?

Comment: Do you know how to describe "increasing" mathematically.?

Comment: What are you hoping to show? For almost any property you can think of, you can find a counter example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information provided on $f$ and $g$ is not enough to deduce how $f-g$ behaves.  Depending on which function increases faster affects whether or not $f-g$ increases, decreases, or is constant.  If $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\frac{x}{10}$ then $f-g$ is increasing, but switch $f$ and $g$ and you get $f-g$ is decreasing.  Similarly if $f$ and $g$ grow at the same rate/are identical then $f-g$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

What you can say about $h:=f-g$ is precisely this:

> For all $0<a<b<1$, the function $h$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$.

This is related to the [Jordan decomposition of such functions](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Jordan_decomposition_(of_a_function)).